# Opportunity Line Item UnitPrice Sometimes not updating in BeforeInsert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, opportunity-lineitem

In my BeforeInsert trigger for OpprtunityLineItemTrigger, I check if the product requires VAT (sales tax in the US) and add it to the UnitPrice if it does.

This works most of the time, but sometimes fails.

Here's the code that does this:

```
boolean vatableEntry = entry.Vatable_Entry__c;
Decimal entryFee = (entry.Registration_Fee_Calculation__c <> NULL ? entry.Registration_Fee_Calculation__c : 0);
// If VAT Applicable, add it to the Entry Registration fee
oli.Vatable_Entry__c = vatableEntry ;
if (vatableEntry){
    Decimal vat = (entryFee * (entry.Event__r.VAT_Percentage__c/100)).setScale(2);
    oli.Cost_Comment__c = '(pre-I) OLI - VATable: ' + entryFee + vat;
    oli.UnitPrice = entryFee + vat;
    system.debug('#### fixEntryOppUnitPrice (pre-I) OLI - VATable: ' + entryFee + vat);
}
else {
    oli.Cost_Comment__c = '(pre-I) OLI - Not VATable: ' + entryFee;
    oli.UnitPrice = entryFee;
    system.debug('#### fixEntryOppUnitPrice (pre-I) OLI - Not VATable: ' + entryFee);
}
```

And here are two OpportunityLineItems, from the same Opportunity, for the same product:

[image: OLI - UnitPrice Correct]

[image: OLI UnitPrice Incorrect]

In the first image, the price is correct - £87.48
In the 'Cost Comment' field, added in before insert (pre-I) you can see the string from the code: 72.90 entryFee and 14.58 vat

In the second one, processed in just the same way - with the same Cost Comment (both of them say it is Vatable), but the price on the OLI is just £72.90 - the vat has not been added.

This works most of the time (I've not extracted the data to give detailed stats, but probably < than 1 in 100 OLI's).

You can also see that the 'Vatable Entry' flag is set for both OLI's.

So, it's really difficult to reliably reproduce to debug in a sandbox, and the fact it works most of the time means the code is correct.
We can also see that the OLI gets updated - the Cost_Comment field is populated in both cases.

Please note - the £0.00 List Price is not part of this. The price for this product, an entry into a competition, doesn't come from a PriceBook but is calculated for each entry - from the Entry__c.Registration_Fee_Calculation__c field - and is the same in both cases.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: i'm puzzled - in your ternary, you have `<>` instead of `!=`; also, are you sure there are no additional triggers on this object or downstream PB or Flow that could alter the value?

Comment: Do you have product schedules when trying to update the UnitPrice? If yes, then you should first remove the product schedules, after removing them you should be able to update the UnitPrice. Please let me know the outcome.